# WCF CallBack Blocks other Callbacks

Tags: c#, wcf, callback, net.tcp

I have a WCF Service which Communicates to multiple WPF Client Applications. The Service uses NetTcpBinding in duplex Mode. Now I have 2 Functions which are called from the Server to notify each Client. One function is called every 50ms with a little amount of Data. (This function is invoked for every Client in a different Task!). The other function is called once, when the client registers on the Backend. This function submits a large dataset to the client.

The problem now is: when the function with the large Dataset is invoked (for one new client), on all clients you see, that they don't get data from the function with the LittleDataset. When the large call is finished everything works as expected.

Is there any way I could solve this? What more infos do you need?

ServiceMode=Session, Concurrencymode=Multiple, UseSychronisationContext=False

Comment: This doesn't surprise me - the way WCF supports duplex has always been a bit flaky. Hardly anyone uses tihs feature. If possible you would be much better off using one way operations over netmsmqbinding than invoking callbacks accross a duplex binding.

Comment: Is there any Document where you can see that this is Problematic? I can't use MSMQ because I also use Silverlight Clients.

Comment: I solved, by changing the order of my callbacks, and Blocking my small calbacks while th big one is active. But it makes no sense to me that it is now working, and before not...

Comment: @JochenKühner how did you achieve this, I am facing similar problem